# retrieve and display user image from active directory with c#

Tags: c#-4.0, active-directory

i have a web site developed with c#. 
this site will be hosted in the local intranet of our organization. 
the users are authenticated from their windows ID using windows authentication. 
i want to display the picture in the active directory of a user, when a user visits the site.

this code enables me to get the user image. with the `Response.BinaryWrite(bb);`          `Response.Flush();` the image gets displayed in a blank page. instead i want to display my picture inside a div in the same page. how can i achieve this?

```
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Linq;


namespace thumbnailTest
{
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String myUser = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];

        if (myUser == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("app_graphics/user.jpg");                
        }

        Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        Response.Clear();
        Response.BufferOutput = true;

        DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry();
        de.Path = "LDAP://";

        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher();
        search.SearchRoot = de;
        search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=" +     myUser + "))";
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccountname");
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("thumbnailPhoto");

        SearchResult user;
        user = search.FindOne();

        String userName;

        if (user == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("app_graphics/user.jpg");               
        }
        else
            userName = (String)user.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0];

        try
        {
            byte[] bb = (byte[])user.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"][0];       
            Response.BinaryWrite(bb);
            Response.Flush();
        }
        catch
        {
            Response.Redirect("app_graphics/user.jpg");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1213474.aspx

Answer (score -5):

You should add an img tag with a src url to your handler you wrote (which should arguably be a HttpHandler for Web Forms)
I'd imagine the url would look like

```
<img src="http://myintranetsite/ADImageHandler alt="" />
```